# Drupal path is not initialized" Error in drupal_path_initialize()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a site in drupal it was working fine, suddenly  it is not running.I am getting following
error message:

```
The file could not be created.
The file could not be created.
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

If anyone has experienced a similar issue I'd love to know how you fixed it!

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: move to drupal.stackexchange.com for better responses.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i moved that question there too.